Attempted vandalism in tag descriptions
I just rejected 2 suggested edits by a user who joined today and wanted to change "pairs trading market-neutral" to "pairs reading is marketing natural". Please be vigilant.
https://quant.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/45472
https://quant.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/45473
